# Alternative syntax for "right of="?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that `right of=` is a deprecated version of positioning syntax. However, sometimes, the node positioning that `right of=` (the `node distance` specifies the distance between the centers of nodes) did offer is useful rather than `right= of` (the `node distance` specifies the distance between the boarders of nodes).

Is there any alternative syntax to realize the positioning behavior like `right of=`?

Comment: look for `on grid` key in the manual

Comment: `right=<dim> of <node>.center, anchor=center` ?

Comment: `(foo)+(2,0)node{}`?